# podio PodioApp::get returning label instead of external_id

Tags: podio

The PodioApp::get API documentation shows the expected output for the fields array as:
"fields":
[
{
"field_id": The id of the field,
"type": The type of the field (see area for more information),
"external_id": External id automatically generated that will never change,
"config": The configuration of the field,
{ ...

I tested this on several of my apps (ex: app_id=25343844) and the API actually returns:
"status": "active",
"type": "image",
"field_id": 215299192,
"label": "Property Image",
"config": {

I can write code to get the external_id (ex: loop on all fields in PodioItem::get) but I want to make sure this isn't my bug. I pulled the results using php code and also using the Submit button on the App Get API page (https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349?code=23618ffedff74b5a8a66ddc89a99e057&state=)

Answer (score 0):

When I use the sandbox here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-area-22349

it returns a 'fields' array which includes external_id properties. Remember that the order of properties in JSON isn't preserved, so it could come after the 'config' property.

[sandbox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDjTp.png)